# how to execute a "in " command in android sql

Tags: android, sqlite

In contacts db of android I am trying to take a set of records that have same account name . 
Given below is the "selection " for the query.

```
selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " =  '1' AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " IN  ( SELECT  " + RawContacts.CONTACT_ID +" FROM  raw_contacts WHERE " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME + "= '" + selectionCriteria +"' )" ;

Cursor = managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, selection, null, order);
```

this works fine in android version 2.3 ..but in jellybean , I cannot use db name as "raw_contacts" directly since it has been changed to "value_raw_contacts".

how can I achieve this with a proper sql command without mentionig the db name like "raw_contacts" directly instead using its CONTENT_URI .

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "raw_contacts";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
     ThisClass.CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "value_raw_contacts";
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: ya... I too thought of this method but we cannot rely on this for a long time. Is there any methods with direct sql commands